# Using RLock inside shared object

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex

i have two threads, every one need to access some shared object. In order to protect this object's data i've defined it like this:

```
class ShareObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mutex = threading.RLock()
        self.data = None

    def get(self):
        self.mutex.acquire()
        result = self.data
        self.mutex.release()
        return result

    def set(self, data):
        self.mutex.acquire()
        self.data = data
        self.mutex.release()
```

Is this the right way of using mutex for protecting the shared data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the right way to protect the data. Every more advanced style would be equivalent to what you wrote.

How I would write it, it does the same but is shorter:

```
class ShareObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mutex = threading.Lock()
        self.data = None

    def get(self):
        with self.mutex: # with unlocks the mutex even if there is an error or return
            return self.data

    def set(self, data):
        with self.mutex:
            self.data = data

    # more methods
```

If `get` and `set` are the only methods the class has and nobody uses the mutex attribute, you could also write it like this:

```
class ShareObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None

    def get(self):
        return self.data

    def set(self, data):
        self.data = data
```